# How to create an automatic mock for built-in objects? (Jest, Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I know that with Jest you can create an [automatic class mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) for an ES6 class. You can do that by calling `jest.mock()` with the filename as parameter, like shown below:

```
import ClassThatShouldBeMocked from "./path/to/the/file.js";

jest.mock("./path/to/the/file.js");

// ClassThatShouldBeMocked is now mocked
```

---

But in my case I want to mock built-in objects like `HTMLElement` or `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. How do I get the path of such built-in objects? Is there another way to achieve an automatic mock in this case?

---

Currently I'm using `jest.spyOn()` to create an spy function for each method of this class, that is called in my code. This works but takes up much more time and effort, when I have to call many functions and methods every time.

---

**Edit:**
Im currently using:

- *jest@28.1.0*
- *jest-environment-jsdom@28.1.0*
- *babel-jest@28.1.0*

Comment: Are you using jest-dom?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Currently I'm not using jest-dom. Does it add functionality that solves my problem? I added a list of the software I use to my post.

Comment: Hmmm maybe. What kind of expectations are you doing on HTMLElement, etc?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I mostly want to mock canvas-operations in my unit-tests. Now I have to call `jest.spyOn()` every time.